# Pie chart VM Memory usage Azure

Tags: azure, dashboard, kql, azure-monitoring, azure-dashboard

Is there a way to make a pie chart for the Memory used/available of my VM for the Azure dashboard?
I tried some queries myself but I can't seem to figure it out.

I saw an example for what I want it to look like but didn't see the code for that.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/loLnJ.png)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/renderoperator?pivots=azuremonitor

Comment: @EllaB Have you had a chance to check the provided solution?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the linked image is from the administrator portal that shows the free and used memory in **Azure Stack Hub**.

For regular Azure Virtual Machines, the key operating system performance indicators related to processor, **memory**, network adapter, and disk utilization can be found within [VM insights](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/rich-insights-for-virtual-machines-from-azure-monitor/) experience.

To access this directly from a virtual machine, perform the following steps:

1. In the Azure portal, select **Virtual Machines**.
2. From the list, choose a VM and in the **Monitoring** section choose **Insights**.
3. Select the **Performance** tab.

[image: VM Insights Experience]

This page not only includes performance utilization charts, but also a table showing for each logical disk discovered, its capacity, utilization, and total average by each measure. This also covers the Available Memory utilization chart that defaults showing the average, top 5th, and 10th percentile.

Additional Reading:

- [How to chart performance with VM insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/vm/vminsights-performance)
- [Query for Percent Memory Used](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-monitor/query-for-percent-memory-used/m-p/674768)